# Drawing Multiple Images on a Panel - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, drawimage, eventargs, paintevent

what I am trying to do, and really struggling to do, is have my application paint several pictures onto a panel, one after another. This is currently coded to work by sending a request to a function to paint an image. It sends the values that correspond to said image, but after that, I'm stuck. I cannot get it to paint anything on my panel. Here is the Function:

```
Function ImageUpdater(ByVal CellNum As Short, ByVal NewImage As Short)
    Dim NewImgLoc As String = CurDirShrt & "\Data\Img\" & NewImage & ".png"
    DrawPic = NewImgLoc
    Try
        InitializeComponent()
        Cell(CellNum) = NewImage
        DrawCell = Cell(CellNum)
        UpdateForm = True
        'PaintMe(panGame, Nothing)
        'e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(NewImgLoc), PicCell(CellNum).X, PicCell(CellNum).Y, CellSize, CellSize)
        'PicCell(CellNum).BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(NewImgLoc)
        'PicCell(CellNum).Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        InitializeComponent()
        Cell(CellNum) = 0
        DrawCell = Cell(CellNum)
        UpdateForm = True
        'PaintMe(panGame, Nothing)
        'e.Graphics.DrawImage(MisImg, PicCell(CellNum).X, PicCell(CellNum).Y, CellSize, CellSize)
        'PicCell(CellNum).BackgroundImage = MisImg
        'PicCell(CellNum).Refresh()
    End Try
    Return 0
End Function
```

The paint related items that were not working for me included the commented lines. They were commented in order to allow me to try different ways of getting the panel to paint.

What do I need to add to this function, to get it to send the images, and their respective locations, to the panel's PaintEventArgs sub, and what do I need in that sub? Or, if I'm not to send it to that sub, what should I do differently?

Here is the PaintEventArgs sub:

```
Private Sub PaintMe(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles panGame.Paint
    While ChangeInProgress
        Application.DoEvents()
        If UpdateForm = True Then
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(DrawPic), PicCell(DrawCell).X, PicCell(DrawCell).Y, CellSize, CellSize)
            UpdateForm = False
        End If
    End While
    Return
End Sub
```

Comment: `I left out a little bit of painting related code` you left out ***all*** the paint code and that is apparently the part that is not working.

Comment: @Plutonix I added in the stuff I left out.

Comment: a) get rid of DoEvents b) get rid of the UpdateForm flag entirely. what is Cell and PicCell?  They are obviously important, but what are they? Is this really a TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: @Plutonix A) Can do, B) Can also do. Cell and PicCell are both integers that refer to locations on the panel. The panel is split into 336 different "cells," and the location to each cell is saved in declarations earlier on in the code. It is a normal panel, cells are not actually there.

Comment: It seems to me that that `While` loop is going to be an issue.  You don't sit in a `Paint` event handler and keep drawing things while other stuff is going on.  For instance, if a drawing is supposed to change multiple times over the course of an action then you need one `Paint` event for each change.  In the `Paint` event handler, you draw what is supposed to be seen right now and then it ends.  If you need to force a control to repaint at any time to change the drawing, you call `Refresh` on it or, preferably, `Invalidate` and `Update`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney But how would I get the function to paint my image? That is what I am not understanding.

Comment: The `Paint` event handler should contain just the `If` block.  Any time you do something that requires a repaint, you call `Refresh`.

Comment: That first snippet is hinkey - what is InitializeComponent?  The Designer usually adds that for FormLoad event, it is not something you should call again.  Your paint event needs a For loop to paint each image at the desired location.  I disagree with @jmcilhinney (a rarity), the way that `If UpdateForm1 is coded, it will draw your stuff once and never again.  You dont decide when to paint - Windows does (unless you want to suspend/stop drawing the images).  It also looks like there is only one image there.

Comment: @Plutonix Okay, from what I am understanding, I have changed my code, but it still is not working. With a break point, I can tell that the Paint sub is called once, but that is it, and it does not paint anything. Also, I removed the InitializeComponent, I read something on the internet that said I needed that before I painted something. My new code is here: http://pastebin.com/ZDYCREcW

Comment: `DrawPic is set once in that goofy first method.  If that is not called, the paint event doesnt know what to paint.  You cant set that or the size/location elsewhere.  To draw multiple images, the paint event has to have all the info so it can...paint all the images.  You need a For loop and I would draw them from resources or load them all from file, so it is faster and doesnt leak.